# React InfiniteScroll with Grid System

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, grid, infinite-scroll

What is up, guys? I have an array of objects, I have Grid container, I map through array and render Grid items. Everything is ok, except all Grid cards get rendered at the same time and I have a long list. So, I decided to add infiniteScroll component. But still all cards got rendered at the same time. Here's what I return outta my component:

```
<>
      {pokemonData ? (
        <>
          <InfiniteScroll
            dataLength={pokemonData.length}
            next={handleChangePage}
            hasMore={true}
            loader={<h4>Loading...</h4>}
            endMessage={
              <p style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                <b>Yay! You have seen it all</b>
              </p>
            }
          >
            <Grid container spacing={4} className={classes.pokemonCardsArea}>
              {pokemonData.map(
                (pokemon, index) =>
                  pokemon.name.includes(searchInputValue) && renderCards(index)
              )}
            </Grid>
          </InfiniteScroll>
        </>
      ) : (
        <CircularProgress
          color={"success"}
          className={classes.progress}
          size={200}
        />
      )}
</>
```

handleChangePage function just sets up page state to page + 1;
And I've got no errors, just a full list rendered and Loading... at the bottom of it.
I didn't find any information about what excactly "next" function should be. But one guy made it setPage function, so I did the same. Everything works for him (he renders pictures, one in a row), but not for me, I guess because of grid system. Did anybody ever succesfully implemented Infinite Scroll to the MUI grid system? I'm out of ideas, I can't fall asleep) Somebody help)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's not that much information about InfiniteScroll + MUI grid system, but finally I'm able to make it work. I've left [codesanbox sample for you here](https://codesandbox.io/s/infinitescroll-component-mui-responsive-grid-system-i3mn8?file=/src/App.js). Not that beautiful, but it will give an idea how to implement it.